# using google api refresh_token

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, access-token

We have a mobile based application, where mobile ask user the offline access to google drive. Google give the credentials to mobile from where it is passed to the server via API. Server access users google drive. 
Mainly include file manipulation according to his or his contacts actions(So the user may not be online at the time).

Our problem is these actions by server can only be done within the expiry period of the access_token which is almost 1hr. expiry_date is also given by google.

We need to access the drive even after the expiry of access_token. We googled and found that we can access the users drive using the refresh_token even after the expiration of access_token. The method described is just to pass the refresh_token and expiry_date along with access_token in the request. But it didn't works. We followed [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)

Can somebody help us on it. How to use the credential given by mobile on server even after the expiry_date.

Comment: You should be using the refresh token to request a new access token.  If you use Googles client library it will handle all that for you https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: so what we should do is: before every file manipulation call with google drive on the server, if the request is after expiry_date, then we must first call the 'getNewToken' method. This would return the new access_token. Update the credentials and then continue with the file manipulation.